# Removing all certain characters from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

How do you remove all certain elements or characters from an ArrayList?

Let's say I have a scanner object like

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
```

And the user inputs something like

```
Bubblesort.=
```

If I wanted to save the characters of the String variable to an ArrayList, I'd use a char ArrayList and then load the characters in using a for loop like so

```
ArrayList<Character> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
    stringArrayList.add(userInput.charAt(i));
}
```

My question is, how do I remove all the characters which aren't letters. Like '.', and '=' so that the ArrayList contains only the word "Bubblesort"?

Comment: Have you tried adding an if statement to filter out characters within the for loop? Or replacing characters of the string before it?

Comment: [Many similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+remove+non+letters+from+string+site:stackoverflow.com)